# How to find the number of values that are not the same between two dataframes

Tags: r

```
df1 <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)

df2 <- data.frame(id = c(3,5,9)
```

How to find the number of values that are not the same between two dataframes

> ```
> for df1 6 (1,2,4,6,7,8)
> for df2 1 (9)
> ```

Comment: You can use `setdiff` `library(dplyr);setdiff(df1, df2)` `setdiff(df2, df1)` or with `anti_join`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WE can use `setdiff`

```
library(dplyr)
setdiff(df1, df2)
setdiff(df2, df1)
```

Or if we need duplicate values as well

```
library(vecsets)
vsetdiff(df1$id, df2$id)
vsetdiff(df2$id, df1$id)
```

Answer (score 2):

Which items in `df2`are not (`!`) contained `%in%` `df1`?

```
df2[!df2$id %in% df1$id,]
[1] 9
```

Which items in `df1`are not (`!`) contained `%in%` `df2`?

```
df1[!df1$id %in% df2$id,]
[1] 1 2 4 6 7 8
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another base R option

- If you want only the length of difference

```
> lapply(list(df1$id,df2$id), function(x) length(setdiff(x,intersect(df1$id,df2$id))))
[[1]]
[1] 6

[[2]]
[1] 1
```

- If you want to see the difference in set elements

```
> lapply(list(df1$id,df2$id), function(x) setdiff(x,intersect(df1$id,df2$id)))      
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 4 6 7 8

[[2]]
[1] 9
```